# OnLoad event when child RadWindow appears (or reappears without reload)

Tags: telerik, radwindow

I have a website running ASP.NET and the Telerik controls. I have a parent window with a button which when clicked on, opens a Telerik RadWindow as a popup. This works fine.

When you close the child RadWindow and then click the button again it displays the RadWindow again fine, but I want to be able to refresh an UpdatePanel in the child window, as opposed to a full postback which the .reload() method would do (but this cause the Postback browser popup).

Is there an event in the child RadWindow which gets fired when it is displayed (not simply loaded). Alternatively, can I fire an event in the Child window, from the Parent Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally your RadWindow is a seperate page or user control and gets re-loaded everytime you open it.  From your parent page you can call a Javascript function in the radWindow by accessing the radWindow object from the RadWindowManager on your parent page:

//this function belongs in your parent page

```
function UpdateRadWindow()
{
  var RadWindow1 = GetRadWindowManager().getWindowByName("RadWindow1");
  RadWindow1.get_contentFrame().contentWindow.MyRefreshFunctionJS();
}

//this function in your radWindow Page/User control
function MyRefreshFunctionJS(){
   //refresh page window / update panel etc
}
```

You can also go backwards calling the parent from the radWindow etc, more documentation here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-calling-functions.html